# Removing time part in IntlDateFormatter

Tags: php, date, datetime, internationalization

I would like to output a localized date and have tried this:

```
$time = new DateTime();
echo IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($time)."\n";
echo IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($time, [IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM])."\n";
echo IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($time, [IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, IntlDateFormatter::NONE])."\n";
```

I get this output:

```
Oct 28, 2015, 2:10:50 PM
2:10:50 PM
20151028 02:10 PM
```

So removing the datepart works fine, but not removing the time part. What am I doing wrong?

You can try it out here: https://3v4l.org/UdtoX

**Edit:**

The reason I want to use `IntlDateFormatter` is to get i18n of the date. For example, I should get different results if I set `Locale::setDefault('en_GB')` and if I set `Locale::setDefault('no_NO')` before using `IntlDateFormatter`. Therefore I don't want to specify the format manually.

Comment: You could just use `echo IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($time, 'Y-m-d')."\n";` and format the date with whatever format you want according to the [date parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: The reason I'm using IntlDateFormatter is to get i18n of the date, so I don't want to specify the format manually. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in PHP. By creating an object instead of calling the static method it works :)

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(Locale::getDefault(), IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
echo $formatter->format($time);
```

Gives the desired output `Oct 28, 2015`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();

$dateFormatter = IntlDateFormatter::create(
  Locale::getDefault(),
  IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
  IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
  date_default_timezone_get(),
  IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
  'MM/dd/yyyy'
);

var_dump($dateFormatter->format($date));
```

Comment: I have updated my question explaining why I can't use your solution, since I don't want to specify the format manually.